# Conceptual Question on ARMA Processes

Tags: time-series, arima

Would love to hear some feedback on a conceptual question I have concerning ARMA modelling.

In particular, I would like to ask if someone could highlight why a time series would exhibit *both* AR and MA like behavior, with a simple example.

For example, it is understood that with an AR process, the current value of the series is a function of past values of the series plus an additive error term (innovation).

Whereas, an MA process is a function of current and past innovations.

Yet, I don't quite understand why a time series would exhibit both behaviors?

Comment: ARMA is an efficient way of approximating an AR or an MA process, so instead of using MA($\infty$) or AR($\infty$) perhaps ARMA(2,2) will be enough.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I appreciate your feedback. I guess what I was asking was more concerning, why a process would exhibit both an AR and MA-like behaviours?

Comment: I know I am not answering your question directly (otherwise this would be an answer rather than a comment), but suppose you have a time series that exhibits only AR behavior. Often it could be approximated by ARMA. The thing is, ARMA and AR may be describing roughly the same thing, so you would just have two different representations of the same phenomenon. Then you cannot say that a time series exhibits AR but not ARMA or ARMA but not AR type of behavior. An analogous argument can be made for a series that exhibits only MA behavior.

Comment: Thank you again Richard. I appreciate your hesitation regarding comments/answers. I should say however, I am not by any means a student. Just a learner in my free time. I appreciate your time, and feedback however :)